# Como/Quando fechar Session do Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

Estou com um erro após fechar Session do Hibernate

```
public String listarTodosClientes() {
    session.getTransaction().begin();
    List<Cliente> lista = session.createCriteria(Cliente.class).list();
    session.close();
    return lista.toString();
}
```

Após session.close() o método toString() gera uma Exception.
Mas se eu retirar o session.close(). O código Funciona. 
E agora posso deixar a sessão aberta?

p.s:retornar úma string foi apenas um exemplo. poderia estar retornando algum item da lista.

Answer (score 3):

RESOLVIDO.

Solução!

```
public String listarTodosClientes() {
    session.getTransaction().begin();
    List<Cliente> lista = session.createCriteria(Cliente.class).list();
    String retorno = lista.toString();
    session.close();
    return retorno;
}
```

Comment: Tem certeza que retornar o `toString()` é a melhor solução para obter uma lista de clientes?

Comment: Estou neste preciso momento com um erro igual ao teu, mas num contexto diferente, Tu na tua classe "cliente" não tens nenhum "Set" implementado que é criada por causa de alguma ligação que essa tabela tem com outra?

Comment: Gustavo esse era um metodo resumido, pois nao queria mandar o codigo inteiro. Na verdade eu retorno um Json. E estou com um outro problema que vou postar em uma outra pergunta. o Gson nao consegue converter a lista chamando o metodo, new Gson().toJson(lista) nesse metodo ocorre uma exception.

Comment: jsantos tem sim, ja resolvi isso em um outro link postei a solução. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40334/erro-ao-construir-json-de-um-objeto-recuperado-pelo-hibernate?noredirect=1#comment79301_40334