# Erro ao construir JSON de um Objeto recuperado pelo Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, gson

Erro ao construir Json de um Objeto recuperado pelo Hibernate.

```
session.getTransaction().begin();        
ArrayList<Cliente> lista = new ArrayList<>(session.createCriteria(Cliente.class).list());
String json = new Gson().toJson(lista); // o erro acontece aqui
session.close();

return json;
```

Log do erro

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Attempted to serialize java.lang.Class: org.hibernate.proxy.HibernateProxy. Forgot to register a type adapter?
    com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$1.write(TypeAdapters.java:67)
    com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$1.write(TypeAdapters.java:61)
    com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
    com.google.gson.internal.bind.ArrayTypeAdapter.write(ArrayTypeAdapter.java:93)
    com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
    com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:89)
    com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:195)
    com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
    com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:89)
    com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:195)
    com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
    com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:89)
    com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:195)
    com.google.gson.internal.bind.ObjectTypeAdapter.write(ObjectTypeAdapter.java:107)
    com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
    com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:96)
    com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
    com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:593)
    com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:572)
    com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:527)
    com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:507)
    com.embrapa.pragasdocampo.resource.PragaResource.getLista(PragaResource.java:32)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1465)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1396)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1345)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1335)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
```

Comment: Isso me parece um erro clássico ao trabalhar com json/jpa (geralmente o erro está presente onde se trabalha com proxys para objetos e/ou relacionamentos 1-N/N-N). Em vez de devolver os objetos retornados pelo hibernate, instancie  novos Clientes, atribuia seus atributos para as instancias novas, e devolva essa lista nova (desse modo, você não estará tentando devolver a lista de proxy de clientes, e sim objetos Cliente concretos).

Comment: Exatamente weyel, o Jeito mais prático e funcional que deu certo foi clonando o objeto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Venho adicionar uma outra solução para essa questão, passei pelo mesmo problema recentemente e pesquisando descobri sobre a serialização utilizando a anotação @Expose nas entidades e sobre o mapeamento do Json manual.

Utilizando a anotação **@Expose** e a instanciação **GsonBuilder** podemos indicar qual atributo vai ser serializado na nossa classe. No exemplo abaixo todos os campos que possuem a anotação @Expose vão ser serializados, os demais vão ser ignorados. (Vamos ocultar getters e setters nos exemplos).

Instanciando GsonBuilder:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
  .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation() //ignorar campos sem a anotação @Expose
  .setPrettyPrinting() //formata o json para imprimir no console de forma mais legível 
  .create();
String jsonString = gson.toJson(Casa);
```

Classe com uma subclasse:

```
public class Casa {  
    @Expose  
    private long numeroEndereco;  
    @Expose   
    private String nomeRua;  
    private String nomeBairro; 
    @Expose    
    private Movel movel;  
}  


public class Movel {  
    @Expose   
    private long numeroSerie;  
    @Expose   
    private String descricao;  
    private String cor;  
}
```

Exemplo de saída no console utilizando println:

```
{
   "numeroEndereco": "1",
   "nomeRua": "AvenidaSaoJoao",
   "movel": {
       "numeroSerie": 1,
       "descricao": "qualquer"
   },
}
```

Nesse caso seria ignorado os atributos **nomeBairro** e **cor** que não possuem a notação **@Expose** e com essa notação indicaria para o GSON que queremos serializar o objeto **movel** dentro da classe **Casa**.

Caso queira mapear o atributo da subclasse diretamente no json temos a opção de fazer a inserção manual. Vamos utilizar a mesma classe, subclasse e Gsonbuilder do exemplo anterior porém retirando o **@Expose** da subclasse, temos o seguinte trecho:

```
public class Casa{  
    @Expose  
    private long numeroEndereco;  
    @Expose   
    private String nomeRua;  
    private String nomeBairro;     
    private Movel movel;  
}  

JsonElement jsonElement = gson.toJsonTree(Casa); //Serializa a classe Casa, como utilizamos o msm builder os atributos sem a notação @Expose vão ser ignorados
      jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().addProperty("corDoMovel", movel.getCor()); // Atribuindo a key "corDoMovel"  e o value getCor() presente na subclasse movel
      jsonStr = gson.toJson(jsonElement); // Serializa o json com o novo atributo
```

Exemplo de saída no console utilizando println:

```
{
  "numeroEndereco": "1",
  "nomeRua": "AvenidaSaoJoao",
  "corDoMovel": "Branco"
}
```

Neste exemplo serializamos a classe **Casa** ignorando o objeto **movel** presente na classe e posteriormente capturamos o atributo cor e inserimos no nosso json que foi serializado.

Espero que com este breve exemplo possa ajudar de alguma forma vocês :). Se conhecerem formas mais otimizadas de solucionar esse problema acrescentem ao post ou corrijam este exemplo.

Answer (score 3):

Cheguei a conclusão depois de várias pesquisas e o problema é que o objeto Cliente tem como atributo um outro objeto Categoria. Os dados do objeto cliente estão em memória, ja os dados da Categoria não foram pegadas do banco ainda, Categoria está referenciado com um proxy, ou seja, o hibernate só pega esse objeto do banco de dados quando vc dar um get nele para não ocorrer problema de dados desatualizados. E não adianta criar um novo Objeto que recebe  outro, pois só está recebendo a referencia, a solução que deu certo é de fazer um clone do objeto. criando um método @Override clone do objeto Cliente. exemplo

```
public Cliente clone(){
        Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
        cliente.setNome(nome);
        cliente.setSobreNome(sobreNome);
        //...
        cliente.setCategoria(categoria.clone()); // dentro de categoria vc cria o mesmo método clone da mesma forma que foi feito aqui.
        return cliente;
}
```

Tome cuidado para não chamar o super do método, pois se existir uma relação N para N, terá que ser tratado, ou vai dar problema.

Não esqueça de criar o método clone na classe Categoria, isso é fundamental.

```
public Categoria clone(){
    Categoria categoria = new Categoria();
    categoria.setId(id)
    categoria.setNome(nome);
    return categoria;
}
```

No meu caso o Hibernate esta devolvendo uma lista de Clientes, logo é só implementar da melhor forma que achar melhor um método que clone todos os clientes para uma nova ArrayList.

Em relação ao custo de processamento, não sou o melhor para responder, mas até agora é a unica solução que achei melhor.

> **Atualização 29 Nov 2014**
>
> Estive estudando um pouco mais sobre JPA e resolvi adicionar mais um
>   pouco de informação nesse post.
>
> Por padrão da JPA:
>
> • Toda vez que um relacionamento terminar em One ( OneToOne ,
>   ManyToOne ) ele será por default EAGER.
>
> • Toda vez que um relacionamento terminar em Many ( OneToMany ,
>   ManyToMany ) ele será por default LAZY.
>
> **EAGER** significa que quando Buscar um Objeto Cliente que tem como atributo Categoria(Outro objeto), no ato do Select Cliente no banco de
>   dados os dados, o objeto categoria serão carregados em memória.
>
> **LAZY** signigica que quando Buscar um Objeto Cliente que tem como atributo Categoria(Outro objeto), no ato do Select Cliente no banco de
>   dados, o objeto categoria não será carregado em memória apenas no
>   momento que o método cliente.getCategoria() for invocado.
>
> Esse é um padrão do JPA, mas pode ser mudado, e possivelmente o
>   Hibernate está fazendo isso.
>
> Pode não ter relação com o meu problema, mas achei interessante
>   compartilhar esse conceito.

Comment: Ambas as classes herdam características de `Serializable`? Se eu não me engano, o Hibernate tem a necessidade de seus modelos serem Serializaveis.

Comment: Sim todas minhas entidades implementao Serializable, o proprio hibernate mapeou automaticamente as tabelas do meu banco de dados criando minhas entidades. Talvez a melhor soluço pode ser essa http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13459718/could-not-serialize-object-cause-of-hibernateproxy mas no consegui fazer funcionar

Comment: Embora o seu problema inicial ainda não é este que você citou (lazyInit/proxy) rs, você iria trombar nele provavelmente logo após resolver o problema das proxys. Para entender o que é proxy, da uma olhada neste link -> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html (e como a própia exceção disse, proxys do hibernate não são serializaveis) []'s